# What are the potential uses of a good R.N.S. system?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

We can consider a [Residue Number System (R.N.S.)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system) that has efficient operations for add, multiply, and compare between two numbers.

**A more rigorous definition**

We can suppose that we can perform the operations above between two non-negative integers $x$ and $y$ with $x \ge y$ in time proportional to $O(x\log(x))$ with $O(\log(x^2))$ memory.  Or further, if it would possibly allow even more uses, if we could perform these operations in time linear with respect to $x$ and $y$.

**What are the potential uses of this system?**

For example, cryptology often uses fairly large numbers, and makes use of such a system.  Also, linear programming and systems of linear equations can make use of an efficient R.N.S.  Also, specialized processors can have R.N.S.'s built in, and could potentially compete with standarized Boolean processors.

**What additional uses would this efficient system allow?**

Comment: I asked if a system like this potentially exists here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/how-close-can-we-get-to-linear-multiply-add-and-compare-on-integers